# Latent class analysis (Mplusautomation)

Tags: r

I am working on a basic latent class model.  I am simply trying to get a latent class model to run.  I am using data from `poLCA` with `Mplusautomation`.  There are 5 variables.  In `poLCA`, these variables coalesce into a 4-class model.  For some reason, I cannot seem to get `Mplusauotmation` to run properly.  Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(glue)
library(MplusAutomation)
library(rhdf5)
library(here)
library(janitor)
library(gt)
library(semPlot)
library(reshape2)
library(cowplot)
library(filesstrings)
library(poLCA)
library(dplyr)

data("cheating")
d = data.frame(cheating)


prepareMplusData(d, "cheating.dat")

m.cfa = mplusObject(
  TITLE = "CFA",
  VARIABLE = "categorical = LIEEXAM- GPA;", 
  ANALYSIS = "estimator = mlr;", 
  MODEL = "factor by LIEEXAM- GPA;", 
  OUTPUT = "TECH1; TECH8;", 
  PLOT = "TYPE = PLOT3;", 
  usevariables = colnames(d), 
  rdata = d
)

m.cfa.fit = mplusModeler(m.cfa, "cheating.dat",run = TRUE)

m.lca = lapply(2:5, function(k){
  body = update(m.cfa, 
                TITLE = ~ "Latent Class Analysis", 
                VARIABLE = as.formula(sprintf(" ~ . + `classes = c(%d);`", k)), 
                ANALYSIS = ~ . + "type = mixture; starts = 250 25;", 
                MODEL = ~ "%OVERALL%", 
                OUTPUT = ~ . + "TECH14;")
  mplusModeler(body, sprintf("lca_%d_cheating.dat", k), run = TRUE)
})

lcacfa = readModels("lca_cheating.txt", recursive = TRUE)
```

What am I doing wrong that is preventing the models from running properly?
The issues I am having are as follows:

1. In the m.lca, I am getting the following warning messages:

> Warning messages for all 4 models: In system(command, intern = TRUE,
> invisible = (!showOutput), wait = TRUE) :   running command
> 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c cd "C:\Users\gehigg01\Documents" &&
> "Mplus" "lca_2_cheating.inp"' had status 1

2. In the readModels, I am getting the following error:

> Error in getOutFileList(target, recursive, filefilter) :    Specified
> target does not exist.   Target:
> C:\Users\gehigg01\Documents\lca_cheating.txt In addition: Warning
> message: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> path[1]="lca_cheating.txt": The system cannot find the file specified

I am not seeing something, and I am too new to R to understand what I am not seeing.  This is my first time using `Mplusautomation`.  I, usually, just use Mplus directly.  Any help getting this to run will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to specify how it doesn't "run properly"? Are you getting an error (if so, include the text of the error)? Are you getting an output, but it seems wrong in some way? Something else?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the warnings and errors I am getting.  Thank you.

Comment: You should try two things: 1 - using full paths to a custom folder, if possible like "c:\\mplus\\cheating.txt". 2 - try to not use  the same name "cheating.txt" both in prepareMlusData and in m.cfa.fit = mplusModeler line.

Comment: I tried both of these, and I cannot get it to work.  Any other ideas.